# Android MySQL Login and Register doesn't work. Unexpected response code 500

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, registration

I'm following this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/
Copy-pasted the php files, only changed the database parameters and the amount of data user table stores. Whenever I try to register a user, I get this in my logcat:

```
03-31 14:07:04.694 11972-12241/com.example.giedrius.keliokliuciuregistravimosistema E/Volley: [192] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for http://giekri.stud.if.ktu.lt/register.php
03-31 14:07:04.746 11972-11972/com.example.giedrius.keliokliuciuregistravimosistema E/RegistrationScreen: Registration Error: null
```

My AppConfig:

```
package com.example.giedrius.keliokliuciuregistravimosistema;
public class AppConfig {
    // Server user login url
    public static String URL_LOGIN = "http://giekri.stud.if.ktu.lt/login.php";

    // Server user register url
    public static String URL_REGISTER = "http://giekri.stud.if.ktu.lt/register.php";
}
```

AppController unchanged:

```
package com.example.giedrius.keliokliuciuregistravimosistema;

import android.app.Application;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

And Registration file:

```
package com.example.giedrius.keliokliuciuregistravimosistema;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.example.giedrius.keliokliuciuregistravimosistema.R;
import com.example.giedrius.keliokliuciuregistravimosistema.AppConfig;
import com.example.giedrius.keliokliuciuregistravimosistema.AppController;
import com.example.giedrius.keliokliuciuregistravimosistema.SQLiteHandler;
import com.example.giedrius.keliokliuciuregistravimosistema.SessionManager;

public class RegistrationScreen extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = RegistrationScreen.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button btnRegister;
    private Button btnLinkToLogin;
    private EditText inputFullName;
    private EditText inputFullSurname;
    private EditText inputAddress;
    private EditText inputEmail;
    private EditText inputPassword;
    private EditText inputPassword2;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private SessionManager session;
    private SQLiteHandler db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration_screen);

        inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Vardas);
        inputFullSurname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Pavarde);
        inputAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Adresas);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_elPastas);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Slaptazodis);
        inputPassword2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Slaptazodis2);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_Registruotis);
        btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_Prisijungti);

        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        // Session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // SQLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if user is already logged in or not
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationScreen.this,
                    MainMenu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        // Register Button Click event
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = inputFullName.getText().toString().trim();
                String surname = inputFullName.getText().toString().trim();
                String address = inputFullName.getText().toString().trim();
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                String password2 = inputPassword2.getText().toString().trim();



                if (!name.isEmpty() && !surname.isEmpty() && !address.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty() && !password2.isEmpty()) {
                    registerUser(name, surname, address, email, password);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your details correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

        // Link to Login Screen
        btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        LoginScreen.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Function to store user in MySQL database will post params(tag, name,
     * email, password) to register url
     * */
    private void registerUser(final String name, final String surname, final String address, final String email, final String password) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_register";

        pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>()
        {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                    if (!error) {
                        // User successfully stored in MySQL
                        // Now store the user in sqlite
                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                        String name = user.getString("name");
                        String surname = user.getString("surname");
                        String address = user.getString("address");
                        String email = user.getString("email");

                        // Inserting row in users table
                        db.addUser(name, surname, address, email);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User successfully registered. Try login now!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        // Launch login activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                RegistrationScreen.this,
                                LoginScreen.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {

                        // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                        // message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting params to register url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("name", name);
                params.put("surname", surname);
                params.put("address", address);
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

I have tried to debug it and it looks to get messed up in this part:

```
StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>()
```

it jumps through everything in the curly brackets right to

```
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
```

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? I can provide the rest of the files if needed.

**EDIT**
Addint Registration php file:

```
<?php

require_once 'DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['surname']) && isset($_POST['address']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    // receiving the post params
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // check if user with the same email already exists
    if ($db->doesUserExist($email)) {
        // user already exists
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "User already exists with email: " . $email;
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // create a new user
        $user = $db->storeUser($name, $surname, $address, $email, $password);
        if ($user) {
            // user stored successfully
            $response["error"] = FALSE;
            $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
            $response["user"]["surname"] = $user["surname"];
            $response["user"]["address"] = $user["address"];
            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user failed to store
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
} else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters (name, surname, address, email or password) is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

P.S. The URLs should be working, because I used them in another login tutorial and it worked fine. But it had only the login part, so I moved to this tutorial which also has registration. And now it doesn't work.
The tutorial which worked is [this](http://androidcss.com/android/android-php-mysql-login-tutorial/)

Comment: Your php error log can give you an idea of what's going on. Considering you haven't posted the code for register.php we can only guess! My guess is line 18.

Comment: Added the register.php file

Comment: What's in the PHP error log? If you hit the URL directly in a browser without posting do you get the JSON encoded required parameters message as expected?

Comment: Ok, figured out why registration didn't work. Managed to fix that (messed up file names, I'm an idiot). But logging in still doesn't work

Comment: PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/giekri/public_html/login.php:0

PHP   2. DB_Functions->getUserByEmailAndPassword() /home/giekri/public_html/login.php:15

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in /home/giekri/public_html/DB_Functions.php on line 52

Comment: At this point I'd probably start a new question. Create a complete and minimally verifiable example. Include your version of PHP.